# Make this including a unique data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As I will have multiple places where this is, I would like to get it to work with a unique data.

Like instead of `<a class="snippet_show_answers" href="#">Se svar</a>` then maybe something like `<a DATA="1" class="snippet_show_answers" href="#">Se svar</a>`, which then should run as a part of my script, so that it only handle for the clicked DATA, and not for all of the boxes.

My HTML is this (With multiple of those):

```
<p class="snippet_answers">Svar: 3 - <span class="green"><a class="snippet_show_answers" href="#">Se svar<img src="images/answerarrow.png" alt="answerarrow" height="14" width="13"></a><a class="snippet_hide_answers" href="#" style="display: none;">Skjul svar<img src="images/answerarrow.png" alt="answerarrow" height="14" width="13"></a></span><hr />
    <div class="answers" style="display: none;">
        <p>blablabla</p>
    </div>
</p>
```

My JS is this:

```
$('.snippet_show_answers').live("click", function() {
    $('.answers').slideDown("slow");
    $('.snippet_show_answers').fadeOut("slow");
    $('.snippet_hide_answers').fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
});

$('.snippet_hide_answers').live("click", function() {
    $('.answers').slideUp("slow");
    $('.snippet_hide_answers').fadeOut("slow");
    $('.snippet_show_answers').fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
});
```

Hope someone understand me, cause I have seen this method before, but I dont know the name of it, or anything.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: `DIV` can't be a child of `P` tag..need to start with valid html

Comment: Okay, thanks for the side-notice, I will fix that :)

Comment: Stop me if I'm misunderstanding you: You're trying to get the JavaScript to only run on the clicked paragraph, but currently the JavaScript is running on every paragraph when clicked?

Comment: Ok, I'll write up an answer

Comment: Sweet. Thanks a lot :D Looking forward to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a reference to the clicked item's parent element and then find its descendants with the appropriate class:

```
$('.snippet_show_answers').live("click", function() {
    var item = $(this).closest(".snippet_answers");
    item.find('.answers').slideDown("slow");
    item.find('.snippet_show_answers').fadeOut("slow");
    item.find('.snippet_hide_answers').fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
});

$('.snippet_hide_answers').live("click", function() {
    var item = $(this).closest(".snippet_answers");
    item.find('.answers').slideUp("slow");
    item.find('.snippet_hide_answers').fadeOut("slow");
    item.find('.snippet_show_answers').fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
});
```

Also, if you are using the latest version of jQuery, make sure to change `.live()` to `.on()`.  `.live()` was recently deprecated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when I use this the `.answers` does not slide for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: @ErikHansen - Change your outer `<p>` to a `<div>`.  A `<p>` cannot contain a child `<p>` and also does not require a closing tag.  When the HTML parser encounters the second `<p>` it automatically closes the first `<p>`, thus changing the DOM hierarchy from what you intended.  The subsequent `</p>` is ignored.  Using a `<div>` for the outer element should resolve this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it to work now :) I will remember the `.closest` call, might be usefull in future.